# Excel import OData feed URL from SharePoint 2016 get 401 error

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, error, excel, odata

I want to establish an OData datafeed in Excel 2013 to connect to a SharePoint 2016 list.

In the Excel, data tab -> from other source -> from OData datafeed. Then I input our SP2016 url:

```
https://sharepoint.com/sites/abc/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/mylist
```

After some loading, Excel prompt for 401 unauthorized error.

However I can browse `https://sharepoint.com/sites/abc/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/mylist` with Chrome. I copy the content and saved as a local text file. In the Excel,  data tab -> from other source -> browse the text file. Datafeed is imported perfectly.

How can I solve the 401 error?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to register excel in SharePoint.

https://piyushksingh.com/2018/12/26/register-app-in-sharepoint/

Comment: The post is talking about App-in. Could you be more specific how to reg the desktop program Excel?